# mac with broken X server brew install git fails

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I login to the Mac through ssh from Kubuntu. getting that far with the old iMac with a broken gui that was gifted to me has been a challenge.

while trying to get more funtionality from the ssh: mac terminal, as I explore the broken OS X gui, I installed homebrew which failed to install the git dependency.

I've downloaded and mounted a git version to try to remedy "brew install git" failure. it didn't help.

```
hdid git-2.8.1-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg
/dev/disk1              GUID_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk1s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal
```

the error that started today's quest:

```
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
```

some things I've tried:

```
macsix:Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal greg$ brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
Error: Git is unavailable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
macsix:Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal greg$ man brew
macsix:Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal greg$ brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/git.rb
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
######################################################################## 100.0%
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
Error: Git is unavailable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
macsix:Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal greg$ ls
README.txt                              VERSION-2.8.1-universal-mavericks       git-2.8.1-intel-universal-mavericks.pkg
macsix:Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal greg$ brew install git-2.8.1-intel-universal-mavericks.pkg
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
Error: Git is unavailable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
macsix:Git 2.8.1 Mavericks Intel Universal greg$
```

any hints will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should post the question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue/question is please? Is it that your Mac is old? Or that you can't install git? Or you can't install homebrew? Or that the GUI is broken?

Comment: Homebrew installed. as part of the installation it attempted to install git, which is apparently needed for brew install anything. what fails is brew install git.                                                                                                                       You must: brew install git
Error: Git is unavailable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q